# Automatic gradle download instead of local gradle in cordova

Tags: android, cordova, build.gradle

I am trying to build my android project on cordova.

I already have android studio installed (alongwith gradle) on my laptop.

However it starts downloading gradle-4.1-all.zip and the downloading takes lot of time which i cannot afford due to slow internet connection.

**Can anyone suggest me a way by which I can use the local gradle file?**

I don't have a .zip gradle file instead I have an unzipped folder in android studio.

```
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\second>cordova build android
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_141
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 2):

past the given link "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip" in your browser or IDM, it will be downloaded faster.

unzip the downloaded zip in "C:\Users\youruser.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all" of your PC location, then rebuild it.